# Given 4 points to a rectangle (that has some kind of rotation), determine if a single point is within the rectangle

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am trying to think of an algorithm to find out if a point is within a rectangle. Finding a point in a standard rectangle without a rotation built onto the lines is a fairly easy task, however if the rectangle is on an angle, the algorithm becomes more complicated.

Comment: Is there a specific problem that is related to code?

Comment: @Marco finding whether or not your mouse cursor is within a rectangle.

Comment: This is just a point-in-polygon test.  I don't think that knowing the polygon is a rotated rectangle actually helps you any.

Comment: Have you read this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon Its the general case for a polygon.

Comment: @PaulJohnson The issue with both of those algorithms is the fact that I only have rectangle points, not lines. And also detecting ray intersections is its own algorithm.

Comment: You can reduce the task to the "easy case" by applying a counter-rotation to the rectangle and the test point.

Comment: @jasonharper: on the opposite, it is much simpler than the case of a general quadrilateral.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following. Say you have points `A (x1, y1)`, `B (x2, y2)`, `C (x3, y3)`, `D (x4, y4)` and `P (xp, yp)`.

0 stage. Find min and max of xn and yn. If `xp < min(xn) or xp > max(xn) or yp < min(yn) or yn > max(yn)` then P is outside the rectangle else we need further calculations.

1 stage. Find four functions `f(x) = ax + b` that produce graphics (lines) which the sides of the rectangle belong to. For AB side `a =  (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`  and `b = y1 - a * x1`.

2 stage. Find which of the sides is leftward/upward. Say AB is upward to CD*. Then find if the system of inequations is true: `fAB(xp) <= yp <= fCD(xp) and fAD(xp) <= yp <= fBC(xp)`. The true will show that P is inside the rectangle.

*You can skip this stage by checking the truth of opposite inequation `fAB(xp) >= yp >= fCD(xp) and fAD(xp) >= yp >= fBC(xp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let a side of the rectangle correspond to the green vector `(Dx, Dy)`. Then the linear transformation (a similarity)

```
X' = Dx.X + Dy.Y
Y' = Dx.Y - Dy.X
```

will make the rectangle axis-aligned. If you apply the same transformation to the test point, the insideness relation is preserved and the resolution is immediate.

[image]

If you have several test points, you only need to transform the rectangle once.